# Get featured image of a page (no post) in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to show the featured images of all the pages, not the posts. I have this code:

```
<?php
if ((is_singular() || is_home()) && current_theme_supports('post-thumbnails')) : echo get_the_post_thumbnail( '12', 'full' ); ?>
<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" class="header-img" alt="" />
<?php endif;?>
```

But this only shows one featured image.

Thank you so much!

Comment: So obviously you passing post id `12` so it will bring the feature image of that post. What you expecting ?

Comment: a loop of featured images in all pages, i know i passing id 12 but how can i get the loop?

Comment: This might be a question that belongs on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use WP_Query to get that,

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id' ) );
```

Or if you want to do by your way you need to fetch all pages first & than loop over it to get thier feature image,

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
); 
$pages = get_pages($args); 
foreach($pages as $page) {
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, 'full' );
}
```

Comment: just change $mypages to $pages to work (I could edit your comment)

Comment: this is retarded, not your solution, I'm sure it works, but for the love of god why do such simple things have to be so god damn hard to achieve in WP??