# how to display featured image of pages

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I am trying to get my pages featured image out for each page. I have set my featured image but nothing seems possible to display the featured image. I have tried to follow from these (such as: 
[Get featured image of a page (no post) in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570413/get-featured-image-of-a-page-no-post-in-wordpress)

[Add a pages featured image to a foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18127263/add-a-pages-featured-image-to-a-foreach-loop/)

[Wordpress Display Child page data: Title, featured image and custom field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557398/wordpress-display-child-page-data-title-featured-image-and-custom-field)

[Get Featured Image of Pages - WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33113930/get-featured-image-of-pages-wordpress)

but still, fail to get my featured image out. when I tried to retrieve my page data, there seem to be no featured image url stored in the array. please help.

```
<?php                           
    $menuLocations = get_nav_menu_locations();
    $menuID = $menuLocations['introBlock_menu']; 
    $primaryNav = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menuID); 
    foreach ( $primaryNav as $navItem ) {
?>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="intro-block">
    <!-- This is where I am trying to get the featured image url -->
        <div class="intro-block-inner">
            <h2>
            <?php  
                echo '<li style="list-style-type: none;"><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="'.$navItem->url.'" title="'.$navItem->title.'">'.$navItem->title.'</a></li></div></div></div>';
                } 
            ?>
            </h2>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not a free code generator. Hire a developer.

Comment: Does the image show up when you `print_r($primaryNav);`? echo a `<pre>` before and `</pre>` after to read it more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create an absolute path of the image url and echo it where you need. Please check bellow example:

```
<?php                           
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
?>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="intro-block">
        <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>">
        <div class="intro-block-inner">
            <h2>Your Heading Element</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```